# How long can I leave a recently cleaned deck without stain?

Tags: wood, deck, cleaning, staining

I have cleaned my deck and was planning on staining it. My problem is the weather is calling for rain everyday for the next 2 weeks.  How long will my deck be ok without stain?

Comment: I need to know how long can my deck sit after being cleaned because i cant stain due to the fact that we are going to have 2 weeks of rain.

Answer (score 1):

Most stains manufacturers recommend a moisture content that measures less than 18-15%, bellow that you are safe to stain. Usually 2 days with no rain is enough.

If you want to be sure, you can always buy a wood moisture meter, you can find some cheap ones for around 25$ at your local hardware store or on Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the deck being unprotected from the rain, then you might consider covering it with a tarp to keep it dry.  An added bonus is when the weather turns back you won't need to wait for it to dry before applying the stain (but I would recommend checking the moisture content as well)